# Blank Page in Spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I followed the steps for installing 2011 and B2B and everything went well.
Hybris Server with cx-for-spa recipe is running
OCC is working and returns the response for powertools-spa
No error is displayed in Chrome Dev Tools
CORS have been already added and Request URL: https://localhost:9002/occ/v2/powertools-spa/cms/pages?lang=en&curr=USD. is returning the response

No errors on the browser's console, OCC or Spartacus logs

angular dependencies as follows

```
    "@angular/animations": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/common": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/http":"~7.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/localize": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/router": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~10.1.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^4.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "~10.0.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "~10.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "~10.0.0",
    "@spartacus/assets": "^3.0.0",
    "@spartacus/core": "^3.0.0",
    "@spartacus/organization": "^3.0.0",
    "@spartacus/setup": "^3.0.0",
    "@spartacus/storefront": "^3.0.0",
    "@spartacus/styles": "^3.0.0",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^10.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.2.1",
    "i18next": "^19.3.4",
    "i18next-xhr-backend": "^3.2.2",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.803.2",
 "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",

 "@spartacus/tua-spa": "~1.2.0",
 "ng2-charts": "^2.3.2",
 "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
 "ngx-spinner": "^8.0.3"
  },
```

Comment: Hi Winston. Since everything seems to be correct with your setup, I would do the following:
* Compare with our Spartacus demo server to see if the http response is somewhat similar
* Retry your build without @spartacus/tua-spa

Answer (score 1):

Please check the schematics version you are using. I would recomend to use the latest:

```
ng add @spartacus/schematics@latest --baseUrl https://spartacus-demo.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:8443/ --baseSite=electronics-spa --ssr
```

Also verify:

- Angular CLI: Version 10.1 or late
- Node.js: The most recent 12.x version is recommended, < 13
- Yarn: Version 1.15 or later

Answer (score 0):

Since everything seems to be correct with your setup, I would do the following to try to pinpoint the issue:

- Compare with our Spartacus demo server to see if the http response is somewhat similar
- Retry your build without @spartacus/tua-spa

Comment: Hi @HackerGil, Thanks for your reply. 
The difference is that local calls only https://localhost:9002/occ/v2/powertools-spa/cms/pages?lang=en&curr=USD, no calls for basesite, currency, etc. I removed tua-spa but didn't work. if it is possible, can you please share dependencies for Angular?

Comment: Angular dependencies are essentially the same that you described above.

Comment: could you please help that what would be the issue for Spartacus calls only pages? endpoint

Comment: Is the call to /pages the only xhr call that is made? We fetch language and currency next, and then components. Also, are you positive that there are zero errors on the browser log console? How about in other browsers?

Comment: just fixed,
uninstalled NPM, Angular, reinstalled Angular 10.2.1, reinstall sample Spartacus, it worked
Thank you